# Pytest - Check if user name and password return 'set cookie' - AssertionError

Tags: python, pytest

I am writing a test that has two assertions:

1 - I send the right user name and password and expect the login method to return true if the header sent as response by the server contains ['Set-Cookie']

2 - I send the wrong user name and expect the login method to return false as ['Set-Cookie'] is not on request.headers.

---

This is where I do the request and check if `Set-Cookie` exists. In my case, it is only return `True` if the login is accepted by the server. If I send the false credentials, the `request.headers` will not contain `Set-Cookie`.

```
if request.headers['Set-Cookie'] in request.headers:
    return True
return False
```

---

My test consists only of checking if the right credentials will get `True` as response and the wrong one `False`.

```
def test_login_user():
    assert login_user('right_user_name', 'btcas1A') is True
    assert login_user('wrong_user_name', 'btcas1A') is False
```

---

When I run my test, the first assertion passes as expected. However, the second one fails. I get an:

```
> assert login_user('right_user_name', 'btcas1A') is True`
E     AssertionError: assert False is True`
E   + where False = login_user('right_user_name', 'btcas1A')`
```

I do not understand where and why the test fails. It seems that the `'right_user_name passes'` the test, and later I get this assertion error. Does anyone knows what is wrong?

I would appreciate any thing that would help put me on the right path to understand how the tests works and all since I am still learning.

---

**UPDATE**

def login():
    xmlFile = xmltodict.parse(request.data)

```
if 'LOGIN' not in xmlFile:  
    print ('Check the xml file used for request.')
    return ResponseFiles.loginXmlResponseError

for i in xmlFile['LOGIN']: 
    if i == 'ANWENDUNG':
        user = xmlFile['LOGIN']['ANWENDUNG']
    elif i == 'BENUTZER':
        user = xmlFile['LOGIN']['BENUTZER']

password = xmlFile['LOGIN']['PASSWORT']

loginPassed = readUserRecordFiles(user, password)

if loginPassed:
    return LoginPassed(user)
return LoginError()
```

if the login passes the method `LoginPassed()` sets the cookie and return the response:

```
response.set_cookie('sessionid', sessionid, path= '/')
```

The whole thing works, my problem is only writing the tests.

---

**UPDATE**

I fixed the `if  'Set-Cookie' in request.headers:` as suggested by [Jon][1]

and it solved my problem.

Comment: Can you please post the whole code `login_user()`? That'll help us out a lot in helping you.

Comment: You're checking that the value of whatever `request.headers['Set-Cookie']` is, is a key in `request.headers`... think you mean `if 'Set-Cookie' in request.headers`...?

Comment: In the 2nd case, the code of the login_user() function is returning True while you expect False so your assertion is False and the error is raised.
We need the complete code of login_user() to be certain but the problem is in this function.

Comment: I think the initial problem was that I was checking the value of the Set-Cookie key, like @JonClements said.
I fixed it like he suggests but now I get a different error:

key = ['Set-Cookie']
def __getitem__(self, key):

    return self._store[key.lower()][1]

E AttributeError "list" object has no attribut "lower"


The __getitem__ method is probably a pytest method.

I tested the response and request with postman and I do not get any cookies when the wrong credentials are sent, that is why I believe the problem is on my test.

Comment: @Fix3r and why is it `key = ['Set-Cookie']` (a list with a single string) instead of `key = 'Set-Cookie'` - an actual string that will support `.lower()` ?

Comment: I dont know. That is something in python collections, probably. I posted a picture.

Comment: Nope - that's you... why did you make the change I suggested: namely `if 'Set-Cookie' in request.headers` - into `if ['Set-Cookie'] in request.headers` ?

Comment: Ahhhh! Thanks, I did not notice this mistake *facepalm*